# Why is my Opencv not responding or doing any action?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo

I am doing the YOLO Object detection in Python Opencv. But for some reason it's not responding. If I just simply turn on the camera without the object detection code, it works fine. But if I add the object detection code it is not responding at all. This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3.cfg', 'yolov3.weights')
classes = []
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with open('coco.names', 'r') as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)
    boxes = []
    confidence = []
    class_ids = []
    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            if confidence > [0.5]:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)
                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)
                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidence.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidence, 0.5, 0.4)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(boxes), 3))
    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidence[i], 2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + '' + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

If I run this code the camera opens but then if I move my hand, it does not move my hand. Is this my code problem or my PC problem? Please help me

And btw the code got a little bit of more spaces or something while uploading to stack overflow, I apologize for that.

Comment: when u pressed a key, does is pass to new frame?

Comment: Not when I press the key, but when I press the X button on the top, you know how the window closes and it opens again. When it opens again, it passes to a new frame

Answer (score 1):

Try give more time to waitKey() function:

```
cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q')
            ^^
```

Read the doc here for reference [waitKey()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7):

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when ≤0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive. Since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time. It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed before the specified time had elapsed.

Also, check the indentation of your code.
Try run this smaller version, if it works, add object detection step by step to find out any other issue:

```
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Or more readable:

```
keypressed = cv2.waitKey(10)
if keypressed == ord('q'):
    break
```

---

#### Try this to test the detector

Try this loop, if the detector is working, you should see on terminal a list of detections.
If you place yourself in front of the camere, you should see an high score at index 0, which is the `coco.names` class **person**.

```
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5) # just for more room on my screen
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), [0, 0, 0], swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    print(output_layers_names) # <-- prints out the list of detections
    layerOutputs = net.forward('yolo_82') # <-- try one layer at a time

    for out in layerOutputs:
        if not np.all(out[5:] == 0): print(out[5:])
    print('-'*50)

    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    keypressed = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if keypressed == ord('q'):
        break
```

Once it works, add the rest of the code step by step, checking the result.

Comment: I checked the indentation of the code before posting it on stack overflow. But I will try the cv2.Waitkey(10) thing. If that works, you get the green tick. :)

Comment: I changed cv2.waitkey(1) to cv2.waitkey(10). It now changes frames but changes 1 frame in like 3 seconds. Do you know how to fix that? (I tried changing the number in cv2.waitKey a couple of times, I did not understand it.)

Comment: Did you trie the smaller version of the code, just capture without inference? Does it run smoothly? On my machine it does. While adding inference it takes longer for each frame.

Comment: By smaller version do you mean only turning on my webcam without object detection?
If yes then I tried that and it works fine. And does the object detection work in your computer?  I don't know if it works on mine because of the lag.

Comment: Check my edit and test the detector. The code I posted works on my machine.

Comment: Ok. I will definitely see if that works. And if it does, thanks a lot man, appreciate that :)

Comment: I tried your while loop and I thought it works, but it did not. If I place myself in front of the camera, it prints 0. But I held my mouse to see if it works, but it still prints 0 instead of 65. 65 is the mouse in coco.names. Does the code work or not? And btw the camera is still laggy.

Comment: I tried a few more objects, And every single one of them prints 0. Like every time. Why does that happen? Some times it prints 0.346247 or something, but every time it prints 0 even if I am not visible in the camera.

Comment: The code I posted works on my machine and shows detections. If in a frame there are detections, it prints a list of size 80. Each element index correspond to the index in https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/data/coco.names. So `0` is `person`, `79` is `toothbrush`. When a person is detected, the list has a non zero value at index `0`. The value is the confidence. So [0.9231, 0.0, 0.0, ....] is a confidence 0.9231 for index `0` which is `person`.

Comment: Oh, but when I hold a few more objects like a book or a mouse, it still prints, 0 with a confidence like 0.987365 or something. Do you have any idea why this happens? And I am not in the camera at all.

Comment: If I hold other objects like a book or something, it does not print their respective numbers in that are in the coco.names. Can you please help?

Comment: Apart saying that the last snippet of code ("Try this to test the detector") works on my machine (it detected even my dog), I don't know how.

Comment: Oh. I guess I will have to try another idea then. :(